# How to create ManyToMany object in django view?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am trying to create product api. Here I have `delivery_option` filed which has a manytomamy relation with my product. when I am trying to create product I am getting some error like `TypeError: Direct assignment to the forward side of a many-to-many set is prohibited. Use delivery_option.set() instead`. How to create the many to many field in django?

```
@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes([IsVendor])
def vendorCreateProduct(request):
    data = request.data
    user = request.user.vendor

    print(data['deliveryOption'])
    print(data['payment'])

    product = Product.objects.create (
        user=user,
        name=data['name'],
        old_price = data['price'],
        discount = data['discount'],
        image = data['avatar'],
        countInStock = data['countInStock'],
        subcategory = Subcategory.objects.get_or_create(name=data['subcategory'])[0],
        description=data['description'],
        delivery_option = data['deliveryOption'],
    )

    product.available_payment_option.set(data['payment'])
    product.save()

    serializer = ProductSerializer(product, many=False)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Answer (score 0):

As error says : 
 *`TypeError: Direct assignment to the forward side of a many-to-many set is prohibited. Use delivery_option.set() instead`*
It means **many-to-many** field does not support direct assignment 
eg. *`delivery_option = data['deliveryOption']`*. 
You've to use `add()` or `set()` method to add values into your many-to-many field do like this

```
product = Product.objects.create(...)
product.delivery_option.add(data['deliveryOption'])
```